# Syntax Error when Using Database Info in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, authentication, syntax

I've been trying to implement a login page where a user enters their username and password and the entered username and password are compared with those in a data table. If the username and password match a message appears saying it was successful.

I've been trying to run the code, but I keep getting a syntax error. I get the following message in visual studio:

> An unhandled exception of type **System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException** occurred in **System.Data.dll**
>   Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'User ID = 'jtenori1' AND [Password] = '''.

Code is included... Please let me know if you need more info and I appreciate the help in advance!

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    Dim LoginID, Password As String

    LoginID = txtLoginID.Text
    Password = txtPassword.Text

    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\person\Desktop\experiment\class\Project\Project41\Project41\project41.accdb")
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE User ID = '" & txtLoginID.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & txtPassword.Text & "' ", con)

    Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (sdr.Read() = True) Then

        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged In")
        txtLoginID.Enabled = False
        txtPassword.Enabled = False

    Else
        txtLoginID.Text = ""
        txtPassword.Text = ""
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid User ID or Password")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: User Id? or USERID ? if it is User Id then Use it like [User ID]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have **User ID** column then you must enclose it in [User ID].

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM UserInfo 
     WHERE [User ID] = '" & txtLoginID.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & txtPassword.Text & "' ", con)
```

**OR**

Cross check column name used in the query with reference to name in database.

**NOTE**: It is highly recommended to use parameterized query.

Comment: What do you mean when you say use parameterized query. I haven't tried your suggestion yet, but plan to soon. I will let you know how it goes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You were right, I was missing the brackets. It's always the simplest things. Thank you for your help!